# how add one JSON array in other JSON array

Tags: json, delphi

I have only a few days experience of learning JSON.

My ultimate goal is to generate JSON for a REST request where `nested2` array must be **nested in `nested1` array**.

Desired JSON object:

```json
 data:{
    "1": "str",
    "2": "str",
    "3": null,
    "nested1": [{
      "4": 1,
      "5": "str",
      "6": "str",
      "nested2": [{
          "7": "str",
          "8": "str"
        }]                // brackets of nested 2     
     }]                   // brackets of nested1
    }                     // bracket of "data" outer object
```

I got this wrong JSON object:

```json
 data:{
    "1": "str",
    "2": "str",
    "3": null,
    "nested1": [{
      "4": 1,
      "5": "str",
      "6": "str"
      }],
    "nested2": [{
      "7": "str",
      "8": "str"
      }]
    }
```

In order not to be confused, please help me solve this issue using only the `System.JSON` library.

My code:

```pascal
procedure Tform1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 jo1, jo2, jno: TJSONObject;  //jno- for nested objects
 ja1,ja2: TJSONArray;
 jp: TJSONPair;
begin
 //creating JSON object 'data'
 jo1:= TJSONObject.Create;  jo2:= TJSONObject.Create;
 try
   jp:= TJSONPair.Create('data',jo2);
   jo1.AddPair(jp);

  jo2.AddPair('1',TJSONString.Create('str'));
  jo2.AddPair('2',TJSONString.Create('str'));
  jo2.AddPair('3',TJSONString.Create('str'));

  //creating ja1 array('nested1'), creating empty object in it and nested objects(jno) and adding it to array
  ja1:= TJSONArray.Create;
  ja1.AddElement(TJSONObject.Create);
  jno:=ja1.Items[pred(ja1.Count)] As TJSONObject;
  jno.AddPair('4',TJSONString.Create('str'));
  jno.AddPair('5',TJSONString.Create('str'));
  jno.AddPair('6',TJSONString.Create('str'));

  //adding ja2 array in ja1 array
  jo2.AddPair('nested1',ja1);

  //creating ja2 array ('nested2'), creating nested objects(jno) and adding it to ja2 array
  ja2:= TJSONArray.Create;
  ja2.AddElement(TJSONObject.Create);
  jno:=ja2.Items[pred(ja2.Count)] As TJSONObject;
  jno.AddPair('7',TJSONString.Create('str'));
  jno.AddPair('8',TJSONString.Create('str'));

  //adding ja2 array in ja1 array.  //how?
  //  jo2.AddPair('nested2',ja2);

  Memo1.Lines.Text:= jo1.ToString;

 finally
  jo1.Free;
end;
```

**Solution:**
As I titled "Adding array in array" isn't right.
We have to:

1. Creating an array,
2. Creating object,
3. Adding object in array
4. Adding pair(object, array)

procedure TfGoodsGroups.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
jo1, jo2, jo3, jno1,jno2: TJSONObject;
ja1,ja2: TJSONArray;
jp: TJSONPair;
begin
//creating JSON object 'data'
jo1:= TJSONObject.Create;  jo2:= TJSONObject.Create;
try
jp:= TJSONPair.Create('data',jo2);
jo1.AddPair(jp);

```
    jo2.AddPair('1',TJSONString.Create('str'));
    jo2.AddPair('2',TJSONString.Create('str'));
    jo2.AddPair('3',TJSONString.Create('str'));
                
    ja1:= TJSONArray.Create;
    jno1:= TJSONObject.Create;
    ja1.AddElement(jno1);
                
    jno1.AddPair('4',TJSONString.Create('str'));
    jno1.AddPair('5',TJSONString.Create('str'));
    jno1.AddPair('6',TJSONString.Create('str'));
               
    jo2.AddPair('nested1',ja1);
                
    ja2:= TJSONArray.Create;
    jo3:= TJSONObject.Create;
    ja2.AddElement(jo3);
    jo3.AddPair('7',TJSONString.Create('str'));
    jo3.AddPair('8',TJSONString.Create('str'));
                
    jno1.AddPair('nested2',ja2);
                
    Memo1.Lines.Text:= jo1.ToString;
finally
 jo1.Free;
end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: That's contradicting: in text/comments you want to nest `ja2` (the **array**) into `ja1` (the **array**), but your picture wants to nest `ja2` into (the unlabeled) `jo3` (the **object** that is the sole element of the `ja2` array). Are you sure you understood what arrays and objects are? Because arrays with exactly one element make no sense - just like `"data"` is directly an object, too, instead of starting an array with just one element (the object).

Comment: @AmigoJack my picture is correct. jo3 object is nested into ja2 array. I will post new picture in order to compare them and then will delete old one.  As for arrays with one element, ja2 may contain elements from one to 1000, for example.  It's vary simplified schema, not real.

Comment: No, you mixed it up: your JSON as 4 pairs of `{}` and you named the 4th of it `jo3` when it should be `jo4`, so you ignore the object in `ja1` completely. Then you'd recognize that using `jno` instead of `jo3` and `jo4` as variables makes you stumble.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes. You was right. There are 4 pairs.  I add 2 variables for nested1 and nested2:  jno1 and jno2. After that I solved problem. I add it in post as 'Update".